# Found a locked phone, how can I access the contacts?

Tags: huawei, locked-out

I found a P30 Lite which I would like to return to the owner. However, I have no way of contacting anyone on the phones contact list as the phone is locked. Is there a way I can recover the data to a PC or somehow access the contacts? Note that USB Debugging is not enabled.

Comment: Make sure the phone has power and network connection is enabled. If the device owner did not made a mistake she or he will use Google connoection to lock the phone and display owner info.

Comment: Try to access its emergency info. Owner might have left a clue there. I usually do so, leaving my other number to "contact me if found".

Comment: If you are really motivated, see if the phone has an IMEI number on a sticker (sometimes under the battery cover if removable) - if you can locate this number, try calling a few prominent GSM servicers in your area.  They might be able to contact the subscriber based on IMEI lookup.